# Protecting routes in React app with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, auth0, react-router-dom

I've created a simple `React` app with `Redux`, `React Router` and `Auth0` which handles user authentications.

I'm trying to create this basic behavior to control access:

- All unauthenticated users will automatically be sent to `/public`
- Authenticated users can access all the other parts of the app
- Once a user is authenticated by `Auth0`, I want to process the `access_token` and send user to `/` which is the `Home` component

Everything is "almost" working the way it should. The problem I'm having is that `render()` function in `App.jsx` is executing BEFORE the `lock.on('authenticated')` listener even has a chance to process the tokens returned by `Auth0`. As a result, the tokens are never stored and the user always seems to be unauthenticated. If I send user to `/login`, everything works fine because I'm not checking to see if the user is authenticated before rendering the `Login` component.

I think the way I'm handling protected routes needs to change. Any suggestions as to how to handle protected routes?

I'm providing the code that you need here. If you want to see the whole app, go to https://github.com/imsam67/react-redux-react-router-auth0-lock

The following is the `App.jsx`:

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {

        const isAuthed = isAuthenticated();

        return (
            <div>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" render={ props => isAuthed ? <Home {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/public" /> } />
                    <Route exact path="/login">
                        <Login />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/public">
                        <Public />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the `AuthWrapper` component where I handle `Auth0`:

```
class AuthWrapper extends Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.onAuthenticated = this.onAuthenticated.bind(this);

        this.lock = new Auth0Lock('my_auth0_client_id', 'my_domain.auth0.com', {
            auth: {
                audience: 'https://my_backend_api_url',
                redirectUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
                responseType: 'token id_token',
                sso: false
            }
        });

        this.onAuthenticated();
    }

    onAuthenticated() {
        debugger; // After successful login, I hit this debugger
        this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult) => {
            debugger; // But I never hit this debugger
            let expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());
            sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
            sessionStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
            sessionStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);

          });
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{ lock: this.lock }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        );
    }

}
```

And here's `index.js` in case you need to see it:

```
import App from './components/App';
import AuthWrapper from './components/auth/AuthWrapper';

// Store
import appStore from './store/app-store';
const store = appStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <AuthWrapper>
                <App />
            </AuthWrapper>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I don't actually see where you're using your "isAuthenticated" property from your reducer. In App.jsx you're referring to your isAuthenticated() util, but since this isn't react state its not going to trigger a re-render if it changes. You need to use your reducer state property to protect your route instead of that helper util.

Comment: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Comment: I switched to using `isAuthenticated` in my `appReducer` as opposed to using the util function but that didn't work. I've read Tyler McGinnis's article but the problem is that I don't want to use something like `/private` for the protected area. I want both the root and whatever comes after it to be protected i.e. `/` as well as `/projects`. The only route that should not be protected is `/public`. So I couldn't really take the idea from the article and apply it to my code.

Comment: Hey Sam, sorry that didn't work. Maybe I'm just blind but I looked through your repo and I don't see where you're calling your action to update the reducer after a user successfully authenticates. Can you point it out to me if its there.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't updated the repo but now I did. I do it in `onAuthenticated()` mehtod in `AuthWrapper.jsx` component which is under `src/components/auth`. It seems the real issue is that routing to a component is taking place before the `onAuthenticated()` method fully executes and stores the `access_token`.

Comment: The trouble is code execution doesn’t even reach that line where I update the reducer. It does hit the onAuthenticated() method initially before authentication is done but unless I send the user to a component that is open to public such as Login, onAuthenticated() never fully executes and stores the tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the changes I made to make this work.

1. I now initialize `Auth0 Lock` in `index.js` to make it global
2. I moved the `onAuthenticated()` listener to `LoginCallback.jsx` component which is where the user is sent after a successful login. I believe moving the `onAuthenticated()` from `App.jsx` to `LoginCallback.jsx` made the biggest impact because the listener in `LoginCallback.jsx` executes before `App.jsx`.
3. On successful authentication, I also use `this.props.history.push('/');` to send user to `Home` component

For full code, please see the repo at https://github.com/imsam67/react-redux-react-router-auth0-lock

Comment: github link is not working at the moment!

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the repository on GitHub. Do you need any clarification on this? You simply need to instantiate the Auth0 Lock as a global object i.e. `global.auth = new Auth0()` or `window.auth = new Auth0()`. From then on, you can access this object anywhere in your app by calling as `window.auth`. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Remember nothing is protected in the client side at all. If your concerned of routing to a component without auth just make sure no data is exposed(assuming they can't get any data without a token) and redirect if they landed there even after your router checks for auth or shows an error.

Answer (score 0):

Remember nothing is protected in the client side at all. If your concerned of routing to a component without auth just make sure no data is exposed and redirect if they landed there even after your router checks for auth.  I think @Sam has it right. The routes may not respond as expected to an asynchronous call changing it or may have odd behavior. I've never attempted a dynamic route this way but always had conditional renders of content components. A better approach may be to send the call and in the then block redirect to a url which the router knows to handle. Just not sure the router handles this very well. Catch the component checking for auth on load and redirect back to log on if not authorized. Sorry I'm not helping much here but conditional routes almost seem like an anti pattern but I guess it could work if we knew how the router renders its data after changes or if it actually does at all(the routes them selves.) So if they were to bookmark the url and try to return back that would be a 404 right? Maybe like a 401 unauthorized showing and redirect or link to log in might be better?

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic routing need to be defined outside of the `<Switch>` scope. Here is an exemple assuming your function isAuthenticated() is a state (Redux or wathever)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

// core components
import Admin from "layouts/Admin.js";
import SignIn from "layouts/SignIn";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();
const loggedRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
    <Redirect from="/admin" to="/admin/aboutUs/whatWeDo" />
  </Switch>
);
const routes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Admin} />
    <Redirect from="/" to="/login" />
  </Switch>
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hist}>
    {checkIfAuth? loggedRoutes():routes()}
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

In this exemple, If you are not login you are redirect to /login.

Comment: Looks like this is all happening in `index.js`. Please keep in mind that I'm using `Auth0` for authentication and it's critical that the code hits the `lock.on('authenticated')` after a successful login. That seems to be real issue here where the router is taking action before the listener has a chance to process the tokens that it receives.